# Orchard CMS Order items by ID

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I need to list items with different `ItemType`s. These types consist of different parts. 
Default content query returns items ordered by ID in ascending order. I need to get list in descending order.

`IContentQuery<ContentItem>.OrderByDescending<TRecord>()` method requires generic parameter (`TRecord : ContentPartRecord`), which I should use to build ordering creteria. But  as I said my content types have different parts.

Some of items do not contain `CommonPart` or `TitlePart`, so I can't use them as parameter to get `ContentItem.ID`.

My actual code looks like this:

```
private IContentQuery<ContentItem> GetContentQuery() {            
    IContentQuery<ContentItem> query = _contentManager.Query(VersionOptions.Latest, 
                                                             Manager.DocConfig.Keys.ToArray());

        if (Manager != null) {
            switch (Manager.SortBy) {
                case SortOrder.Id: return query;
                                   // return query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cpr => cpr.Id);
                case SortOrder.Published : 
                                    return query.OrderByDescending<CommonPartRecord>(cpr => cpr.PublishedUtc);
                case SortOrder.TitlePart : 
                                    return query.OrderBy<TitlePartRecord>(tp => tp.Title);
                case SortOrder.Custom :
                                    var sf = Manager.SortFunc;
                                    return (sf == null) ? query : sf(query);
            }
        }

        return query;
    }
```

is it possible?

Comment: How about `.OrderByDescending<ContentPartRecord>(c => c.Id);`?

Comment: @devqon `ContentItem` does not contain `ContentPartRecord` directly.  other `Part` classes inherite from it. So using `OrderByDescending<ContentPartRecord>()` throws an exception. Each `ContenItem` always contains only `InfoSetPart`, but it doesn't inherite from `ContentPart`

Comment: You are correct, my bad :)

Comment: Why do you want to order by id?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy actually I want to sort them in creation order (they are equal, right?), but anyway I don't have `CommonPart` in each item to get `CreationDate`.

Comment: If you want to be able to sort them in creation order, then add the common part. It has a creation date, which is there for exactly that purpose. The id is not designed for that, and won't even be reliable: SQL Server make no guarantee as far as I know that ids are going to be created in a specific order.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy ok, it is clear about `CommonPart`, thanks. But `identity` generates as `seed + increment`, `id` increments every time you insert new row (create item) and  identity column always generates increasing sequence. I see nothing at this MSDN page to contradict this.

Comment: I can think of several scenarios where the id will be completely de-correlated with an ascending creation date. Import is one. Just don't do that. Even if it worked, it would be a dirty hack. Just use the creation date, which is designed for exactly that.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy yep, I understand. but if add `CommonPart` all existing items would have `null` values. My idea was that there are different types of contents, For example Create/Publishing date is actual part of content for such items like `NewsItem`, `BlogPost` and so on, In other cases (products catalog, companies list) I don't need such data as content, but I need it to see which items I added last (in admin panel). So there are 2 different tasks, but with one solution, I'm not sure it is a good approach.
anyway, post your answer about `CommonPart`, and I'll accept it. thanks.

Comment: Null values are not a good reason to not use the right part, just a reason to do a left join. Plus, the common part really should be on all types. It's not a coincidence that it's added automatically when you create a type from the admin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The creation date on the common part is the correct way of ordering by creation date. Using the id is a hack that can fail in a number of ways. The common part should really be on all content types.